# Create a Grid List with Links

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a grid of items that contain an image, a title, and a description. Each one the items in the grid needs to be a link (I want the list item to act as a link). The issue I'm having is making the entire list item a link, it seems to only work when there is a child element of the `<a>` (eg. if there is empty space in the `<li>` clicking in this space does nothing). In the demo the first item has no description and if you click below the title nothing happens.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tojz8x5z/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="grid-list">
    <li>
            <a class="grid-list-content" href="#">
                <img class="grid-list-icon" src="https://www.wds-solutions.com/images/color_swatches.png" />
                <p class="grid-list-title">Title</p>
                <p class="grid-list-description"></p>
            </a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <div class="grid-list-content">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="grid-list-icon" src="https://www.wds-solutions.com/images/color_swatches.png" />
                <p class="grid-list-title">Title</p>
                <p class="grid-list-description">Some Description. Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.grid-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.grid-list li:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
.grid-list-content {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.grid-list-icon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.grid-list-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.grid-list-description {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `li` just to put the `a` in place and style the `a` as your current `li` after define them as block elements with `display: block`.

Here it is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tojz8x5z/1/).

However, your HTML is invalid. You shouldn't put block elements inside inline elements (i.e. `p` inside the `a`).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was trying to get it to do. Also thanks for pointing out my invalid HTML, I didn't know that :)

Comment: Glad to help! You can change your `p` with `span` and make it valid.